# FromUri binding when querystring is empty

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

If we have the following controller action in Web API

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetRoutes(
            [FromUri] MapExtentQuery extent,
            [FromUri] PagingQuery paging)
        {
        ...
}
```

with

```
class MapExtentQuery {
  public int X { get;set; }
  public int Y { get; set; }
}

class PagingQuery {
  public int Skip { get; set; }
  public int Top { get; set; }
}
```

and we make a `GET` request to `/routes` both parameters (`extent` and `paging`) will be `null`.

If the request contains at least one querystring parameter, for instance

```
/routes?x=45
```

then both complex parameters will get initialized, so in the case of the 2nd route

```
extent.X = 45
extent.Y = 0
```

`paging != null` (but `Skip` and `Top` will be 0 of course).

Why does the `[FromUri]` binder work this way? It makes little or no sense. 
I would understand if it initialized only the parameter that contains a property that matched at least one of the querystring values.

The problem is, this behaviour requires us to check when parameters are null (which happens only in the case that no querystring parameter was provided) and then initiliaze them ourselves.

Because obviously those complex params might have constructors which would set some property values to default.

Answer (score 0):

It is because when you do not have query string and the parameters have FromUri attribute, the parser for the query string does not run and all values are not binded - you receive null.

If you have query string, the binder runs and instantiates all FromUri parameters and primitive types with their default values and then tries to fill in the properties from the query string values. This leaves you with two instantiated parameters but only one having the populated value because that is all the query string has.

As for why it works this way - most likely performance - this way they will not need to find which parameters they need to instantiate - they instantiate all of them and then find the properties. It is faster and performance is critical in the action and model binding.